# SOLVED Custom Add rewrite rule and Get string

Tags: themes, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, terms

I have a problem, I try to create clean urls for seo. but I do not get any parameters using GET, which is wrong in my code

```
add_action( 'init', 'listing_search_url' );
  function listing_search_url()
  {
    add_rewrite_tag('%type%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%search_location%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^custom(/([^/]+))?/(/([^/]+))?/?',
        'index.php?page_id=23&type=$matches[2]&search_location=$matches[4]',
        'top'
    );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
  }
```

this work but have errors so i just make a change and work perfectly

```
function wpd_foo_get_param() {
    if( false !== get_query_var( 'search_location' ) ){
        $_GET['search_location'] = get_query_var( 'search_location' );
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpd_foo_get_param' );
```

This code work

```
add_action( 'parse_query', 'listing_get_query_vars' );
 function listing_get_query_vars() {
     //if you use - _ + on your url the form just recive a space
    if(!empty( get_query_var( 'search_location' )) ){
        $_GET['search_location'] = str_replace(array('-','_','+'),' ',get_query_var( 'search_location' ));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Using `flush_rewrite_rules();` that way is going to cause you problems. It should only be run once on activation.

Answer (score 1):

The values parsed out of internal rewrites don't end up in `GET`, you have to use `get_query_var('search_location')` instead.

If you have code that you can't edit that relies on `GET`, you can try to set them manually-

```
function wpd_foo_get_param() {
    if( false !== get_query_var( 'search_location' ) ){
        $_GET['search_location'] = get_query_var( 'search_location' );
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpd_foo_get_param' );
```

Comment: i Get this code with your function 

Array ( [search_location] => [type] => )

i dont get the values, you know why